# Apache Royale : equivalent of enabled property on j:Button

Tags: disabled-control, apache-royale

I have issue on using "enabled" with `j:Button`.

I know that I must add functionality with this bead :

```
<j:Button id="bp_next" text="Next" >
    <j:beads>
        <j:Disabled/>
    </j:beads>
</j:Button>
```

But now I have the button showing disabled state.

How to change enabled/disabled with AS3 code as there is no `enabled` property on `j:Button` ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this can be achieved.

### Access the bead dynamically on the button

```
(bp_next.getBeadByType(Disabled) as Disabled).disabled = true|false;
```

or,

```
Disabled(bp_next.getBeadByType(Disabled)).disabled = true|false;
```

### Bind a variable to the bead's disabled field

```
<j:Button localId="bp_next" text="Next" >
    <j:beads>
        <j:Disabled disabled="{someVariable}"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:Button>
```

In AS3:

```
someVariable = true|false;
```

### Add an id to the disabled bead

```
<j:Button localId="bp_next" text="Next" >
    <j:beads>
        <j:Disabled localId="bp_next_disabled"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:Button>
```

In AS3:

```
bp_next_disabled.disabled = true|false;
```